# orgchart getOrgChart not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, orgchart

i'm trying to use the getOrgChart library in my page, but my browser keeps insisting it is not a function:

Here's the code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="getorgchart.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" src="getorgchart.css">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
 $("#orgStaffing").getOrgChart({
                                theme: 'vivian',
                                primaryColumns: ['name','division','project','email'],
                                imageColumn: 'image',
                                gridView: true,
```

Comment: Can you post a complete verifiable example? Are you sure that getorgchart.js is being loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it's either not being loaded or its not recognizing the function name (I even put the js file in the same directory as the web page so it could locate that file, but it still said it could not locate the function.

Comment: Ok, so a full example would help.

Comment: @mherzig `$("#orgStaffing").getOrgChart({
                                theme: 'vivian',
                                primaryColumns: ['name','division','project','email'],
                                imageColumn: 'image',
                                gridView: true,
datasource: [ {id: 1, parentId: null, name: 'John Smith', division: 'Inbound', project: 'West', email: 'jsmith@company.com', image: 'johnsmith.jpg'}, {id: 2, parentId: 1, name: 'Jane Doe', division: 'Inbound', project: 'West', email: jdoe@company.com', image: 'janedoe.jpg'}, ...]});});`

Answer (score 0):

Add a quote before the second email 'jdoe@company.com'

I have tried to replicate your issue

```js
    $("#orgStaffing").getOrgChart(
        {
            theme: 'vivian',
            primaryColumns: ['name','division','project','email'],
            imageColumn: 'image',
            gridView: true,
            dataSource: [ 
                    {id: 1, parentId: null, name: 'John Smith', division: 'Inbound', project: 'West', email: 'jsmith@company.com', image: 'johnsmith.jpg'}, 
                    {id: 2, parentId: 1, name: 'Jane Doe', division: 'Inbound', project: 'West', email: 'jdoe@company.com', image: 'janedoe.jpg'}
            ]
        });
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#people {width: 100%;height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css">
<div id="orgStaffing"></div>
```

It works

Please make sure that the dataSource is valid JSON object.

Comment: Here is an example of the objects being created:  `$("#orgStaffing").getOrgChart({
  theme: 'vivian',
  primaryColumns: ['name', 'division', 'project', 'email'],
  imageColumn: 'image',
  gridView: true,
  datasource: [{
    id: 497,
    parentId: 848,
    name: 'Maria Lopez',
    division: 'Inbound',
    project: 'East',
    email: 'mlopez@company.com',
    image: 'mlopez.jpg'
  }, {
    id: 570,
    parentId: 175,
    name: 'Chad Smith',
    division: 'Inbound',
    project: 'East',
    email: 'csmith@company.com',
    image: 'csmith.jpg'
  }`

Comment: please double check that the jquery is being loaded http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js